# View each frame of video and delete/edit them

Tags: windows, gratis, video, video-editing

I'm looking for a program that lets me view *each and every* frame of a video, and edit / delete specific ones.

I want the program to:

- be free
- allow me to *view* each frame and delete a group of them by selection
- run on Windows 7 64-bit (even better, OSX 10.6.8 :)
- have a GUI
- be compatible with major video formats, specifically `.mov` files

Bonuses:

- add transitions between frames
- edit frames by changing color/saturation/blur etc. of each frame

Note: I'm ***not*** looking for a program to *export* frames as pictures and save them. I'm looking for a program that allows me to *view* each frame, delete a group of frames, and hopefully draw on them, and then save the video again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Avidemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/download.html):

- free and open source
- Windows/Linux/Mac
- GUI
- allows to view each frame and delete a group of them by selection
- compatible with major video formats (usually no need to install any additional codec)

[image: Avidemux UI]

Comment: it can also export frames to `png` / `jpg` / `bmp`

Comment: As I remember this also can read/restore corrupted files. Such that make VirtualDub crash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/):

- free and open source
- Windows
- GUI
- allows to view each frame and delete a group of them by selection:

[image]

- compatible with major video formats such as .mov files: you need to download some import plugins/filters. I personally use the [FFMPEG Input Driver](https://code.google.com/p/ffinputdriver/) (32-bit, I had issues with 64-bit) which provides support for 31 video formats

Comment: You still like VirtualDub? 
The last verision of virualdub was on 2013.

Comment: @Amina Well it's good enough for my needs :) I guess I would use Adobe Premiere Pro if I needed more features.