# Software that will blur (obfuscate, hide, pixelate) part of the video automatically

Tags: windows, video, video-editing

I am looking for freeware, open source, or commercial software (under $20 one-time license) for Windows XP or Windows 7. I want to edit videos by hiding personal information on the video before I submit it to a support web site. I know software such as Adobe Premiere has a feature such as blur. In SnagIt, they have a similar feature called pixelate for still images. I am looking for something similar. Ideally, the video editing software should be able to track subsequent frames and blur that area of the video.

Comment: Please state your required (or preferred) operating system or don't you mind?

Comment: Have you looked at other questions from the video-editing tag? (like this one: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7296/view-each-frame-of-video-and-delete-edit-them) Some might be useful to you.

Comment: I see. Could you edit this into your question?

Comment: You could buy adobe premiere for one month through creative cloud to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On SuperUser, there is an answer using FFMPEG to blur a portion of the screen for a set time. FFMPEG is open source.

https://superuser.com/questions/901099/ffmpeg-apply-blur-over-face

Answer (score 1):

YouTube now offers the ability to blur parts of the video and track the movement of that object, so blurring is easy.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9057652

1. upload your video to YouTube privately
2. blur the video
3. Download the processed video using [youtube-dl](https://youtube-dl.org/)
4. Delete the video from YouTube.

Comment: Youtube is good but the issue is that it takes forever to process a blurred video 2 weeks here  https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/1391698/my-video-has-been-processing-after-i-added-custom-blur-it-has-been-processing-for-a-few-days-now?hl=en and https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/ay4osn/face_blur_processing_time/ 1 day here. And youtube doesn't let you download the blurred video until it's processed.